# Easy inequality going wrong

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, arithmetic

> **Question to solve**: $$\frac{3}{x+1} + \frac{7}{x+2} \leq \frac{6}{x-1}$$

**My method:**

$$\implies \frac{10x + 13}{(x+1)(x+2)} - \frac{6}{x-1} \leq 0$$
$$\implies \frac{4x^2 -15x-25}{(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)} \leq 0$$
$$\implies (x-5)(4x+5)(x-1)(x+1)(x+2) \leq 0$$

Using method of intervals, I get:

For $x\leq-2, -5/4\leq x \leq -1$ and $-1\leq x\leq1$, x is less than or equal to zero.

But, this range i got is incorrect. Where did I go wrong then?

Comment: Use \implies for the arrows.

Comment: @Mattos Done. Thanks.

Comment: consider the domain, exclude plus minus 1and -2

Comment: The method seems good but you must take $1<x\leqslant 5$ and not $-1\leqslant x\leqslant 1$. In addition some values must not be taken.

Comment: test with $x=0$, for which the inequality is false.

Comment: just like @5xum does arrange the zeros is descending order as $(x+2)(4x+5)(x+1)(x-1)(x-5).$  each factor is linear, so the sign changes across each one of them whether it is across a zero or across a vertical asymptote.  what is left is check the sign between one of these points.

Comment: @Abel In fact, in *ascending* order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is right at the end. Your polynomial changes sign at the points $-2,-\frac54, -1, 1, 5$, meaning that it is:

- **Negative** on $(-\infty, -2)$
- **Positive** on $(-2,-\frac54)$
- **Negative** on $(\frac54, -1)$
- **Positive** on $(-1,1)$
- **Negative** on $(1, 5)$
- **Positive** on $(5,\infty)$

As for the precise values in which the sign changes, you must be careful, because $$(x-5)(4x+5)(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$$ may be defined on the whole real line, but the fraction $$\frac{(4x+5)(x-5)}{(x+1)(x-1)(x+2)}$$
is **NOT** defined on $x=1,-1,-2$, so the inequality cannot hold for these three numbers. It *does* hold for $x=-\frac54$ and $x=5$, however, so your whole answer is

$$x<-2\text{ or }-\frac54 \leq x < -1\text{ or } 1<x\leq 5$$

Comment: Both $\;-\frac54\;,\;\;5\;$ are *contained* in the solution set.

Comment: @Timbuc I know. But the polynomial is not *negative* on that set. I added a discussion about the border values.

Comment: @Timbuc You're right, of course. just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

After you reached the stage

$$ (x-5)(4x+5)(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)\le 0\stackrel{\div 4}\iff$$

$$ (x+2)\left(x+\frac54\right)(x+1) (x-1)(x-5)\le0$$

and since all the factors are with *odd* exponent, you can apply [the snake method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130716/solving-the-inequality-x23-x-le-4), and get the solution

$$x<-2\;\;,\;\;\;or\;\;\;-\frac54\le x<-1\;\;,\;\;\;or\;\;\;1<x\le 5$$